# Migrating Django App following error come. Anybody have answer?

Tags: python, django, migration

//commandline manage.py migrate command//

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "C:\Users\Crisp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "E:\DjP\blog\idaneram\blog\models.py", line 6, in <module>
        class Post(models.Model):
      File "E:\DjP\blog\idaneram\blog\models.py", line 13, in Post
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_post')
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on_delete is required in django 2.0
https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey